# viewWillTransitionToSize not called in iPad Simulator

Tags: ios, rotation, simulator, viewwilltransitiontosize

I'm trying to respond to rotation on the iPad, by overriding

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size 
   withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator;
```

I've noticed that `viewWillTransitionToSize` gets called on my physical iPad, but not on the simulator, even with the same OS version (10).

Is there a setting on the simulator that I can use to make it respond, or is it a bug in the simulator? If there's no setting, how can I test my app on earlier OS versions using the simulator?

Answer (score 6):

Check your Parent view controller, if its calling super's viewWillTransitionToSize then only child view controller will be able to get call for this method. If you are using subclass of Navigatiopn controller or tabbarcontroller then add these methods and call super's method.

Comment: But wouldn't that have the same effect on both the physical iPad and the simulator? My problem is that it works on the iPad, but not on the simulator